# Clearing edge detect registers (GPEDS0/GPEDS1) crashes Raspbian Stretch

Tags: gpio, raspbian-stretch, kernel

I've been working on [a PHP library](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi) for Raspberry Pi for a few years now, and since (not sure specifically which) a version of Raspbian Stretch, the Pi becomes completely unresponsive when clearing the edge detect bits.  This happens regardless of if I use `dev/gpiomem` or `dev/mem`. It seems strange to be able to crash the system entirely as an unprivileged user.  It happens regardless of whether [native PHP calls](https://github.com/calcinai/php-ext-mmap) or [a Python mmap proxy](https://github.com/calcinai/php-mmap) are used.

Have there been any changes to the kernel that could possibly cause this?

I've tried previous versions of the code (which were definitely working) in the current Raspbian release and they no longer work. **All versions of the code *still* work in earlier versions of Raspbian**

As an aside, I've noticed that no versions of the PWM code work anymore either, and can only assume that this is related.  I've had a look through pigpio and WiringPi and can't see any measurable difference to how I'm interacting with the registers.

There's some more context on [the Github issue](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi/issues/14)

Comment: `earlier versions of Raspbian` - what is the *latest* earlier version you know works

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure specifically, but jessie/4.4.41 is definitely ok. I'll see if I can find a live stretch install to test (that's not current)

Comment: Well, that's more information than you had - could well be a "breaking" change between jessie and stretch!

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, I thought that could be the case but as I mentioned I couldn't  see any significant changes in the other libraries between those versions..

Comment: what if it's kernel or firmware? Just speculating

Comment: I'll take any suggestions! Any ideas on how to even try and debug that?

Comment: On the point "It seems strange to be able to crash the system entirely as an unprivileged user". You are crashing it because you are changing the GPIO registers.  To do that you are a privileged user - using either root or member of group gpio permissions.

Comment: @joan I understand how the unix permissions work, but I was under the impression that `/dev/gpiomem` is an isolated segment of memory specifically for the GPIO registers, that's why I had ruled out accidentally writing to a wrong address.  Is this not the case, or is it somehow possible to upset the whole system by setting something in the wrong order?

Comment: The GPIO registers are privileged.  Linux uses GPIO itself, e.g. for SD card access and kernel drivers for such as 1-wire, I2C, SPI, serial, and related interrupts.  It is quite possible to screw up the system by writing the wrong value to the wrong GPIO register.  I know because I have done just that.

Comment: @calcinai A reasonable assumption is you are clearing interrupts for GPIO being used by Linux.  I think as a minimum we need to see the code you use to clear interrupts.

Comment: @joan Good to know! I thought `/dev/gpiomem` could only access the GPIO (not I2C, SPI, serial etc) so that'll be useful! With regards to how it's being set, it's just a rewriting what was read from the status - https://github.com/calcinai/phpi/blob/master/src/PHPi/Pin/EdgeDetector/StatusPoll.php#L156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year on, an answer!

Adding `dtoverlay=gpio-no-irq` to /boot/config.txt fixes it.

Previously the kernel would automatically disable interrupts when you set one of rising/falling edge detection methods but that apparently stopped happening, causing a kernel panic.

Seems to be the same thing that was happening [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103543/pi-locking-up-trying-to-use-rising-falling-edge-detection)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.